# naming convention for .tpl.php in drupal 7 for custom content type

Tags: theming

I have created content type named **basepage** and have created content **test**
My page url is

> ?q=basepage/test

what should my .tpl.php page name
like (node--1.tpl.php)

Comment: Your question title talks about content types but your question also refers to a specific node. To be clear, do you want to theme all nodes of that type or just the test node?

Answer (score 3):

Overriding `node.tpl.php` for a specific content type is very simple.  The naming convention is `node--machinename.tpl.php`. For `machinename`, use the machine name of the content type with underscores replaced by hyphens. You can inspect the machine name if you navigate to Administration → Structure → Content types.  If you just want the override to apply to a single node (as opposed to all nodes of this content type), add the path replacing all slashes in the path with a double hyphen.

Provided you want to override the *node* template for path *test*, your template should be named:

```
node--basepage--test.tpl.php
```

No extra actions are required. Just create it (usually by copying it from the theme's `node.tpl.php` to `node--basepage.tpl.php`), modify it and place it inside the themes `templates/folder`.

---

Provided you want to override *page* template `page.tpl.php` based on the content type being displayed, the naming convention is the same, but you need to do some extra legwork:

1. Open the template.php file in your theme for editing.
2. Look for a function called THEME_preprocess_page (replace THEME with the theme's name).
3. If this function already exists, you will need to add your code to it inside an if-statement that goes at the end of this function, just before the closing bracket  Otherwise, if it doesn't exist, you'll need to create a new function.

This is how the function should look like:

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  // If the function already exists, just leave the code here intact, and add
  // the three lines below to the end.
  if (isset($vars['node']->type)) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $vars['node']->type;
  }
}
```

Now, copy the theme's `page.tpl.php` to a file named `page--machinename.tpl.php` and place it inside the themes `templates/folder`.

Provided you want to override the *page* template  for path *test*, your template should be named:

```
page--basepage--test.tpl.php
```

for Drupal 7.

Comment: I don't think node--basepage--test.tpl.php is an option for the path "test".  Node templates don't have path based suggestions out of the box. page--basepage--test.tpl.php also wouldn't be one. Page templates have suggestions based on path, but internal path, not aliased path. Also, the path used in the OP is basepage/test not just test.

Comment: @rooby, OK. I may have extrapolated a bit by combining content type-based and path-based overrides.  You've asked the OP a very good question.  I'll do some testing and clean up the answer after the OP had made it clearer what the question is.